# combine grep sed and while

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

Trying to modify an svg so that if a string from a file apears in the line, I change the colour to red.  ie:

```
while read -r LINE; do cat file.svg | grep ""$LINE" | sed 
's/rgb(0,0,0)/rgb(1,0,0)/s; done < file.txt
```

It doesn't work becase the input file is unchanged - I need something like sed -i but how can I put this into the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
cat file.svg | grep ""$LINE" | sed 's/rgb(0,0,0)/rgb(1,0,0)/"
```

to this:

```
sed -i.bak "\~$LINE~{s~rgb(0,0,0)~rgb(1,0,0)~g;}" file.svg
```

This is assuming `$LINE` doesn't have `~` character or any other regex meta character